# Replacing values with for-loop in array in Java

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

I'm trying to set the first and last row of an array to `1` in Java, but only the first element in the array gets changed. My code looks like this:

```
public void createArray(int height, int width){

        this.boardArray = new int [height][width];

        for (int i = 0; i < height; ++i){
            for (int j = 0; i < width; ++i){
                if (i == 0 || i == height){
                    this.boardArray[i][j] = 1;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

But when I do this, I get this result:

```
1 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
```

But I can't figure out why.

Any suggestions on how to solve this would be appreciated, I'm new to Java so bear with me.

Comment: `i== height` will never be true.

Comment: If you want to change the first and last rows, don't use 2 loops as you're wasting processing time on all the rows that you're leaving alone.

Comment: That is: `for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) { this.boardArray[0][x] = 1; this.boardArray[height - 1][x] = 1; }`.

Comment: @Phylogenesis When I run these two loops it just runs and runs, does it really take that long to run this piece of code? I'm used to Matlab where those operations take like 0.1 seconds.

Comment: @frank21 2 loops? There's only 1 loop in my example and it should take virtually no time to complete.

Comment: @Phylogenesis Sorry I was not specific enough, I was talking about my own code.

Comment: The answers below tell you what is wrong with your code. You've mistyped an `i` for a `j` twice in your for loop definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the correct code looks like this:

```
public void createArray(int height, int width){

    this.boardArray = new int [height][width];

    for (int i = 0; i < height; ++i){
        for (int j = 0; j < width; ++j){ //change i to j
            if (i == 0 || i == height - 1){ // also fill last row with ones
                this.boardArray[i][j] = 1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But you do not have to iterate through the whole array to access the first and the last row. So another way with better performance would look like this:

```
public void createArray(int height, int width){

    this.boardArray = new int [height][width];
    if(height > 0) {
        Arrays.fill(this.boardArray[0], 1);
        if(height > 1) {
            Arrays.fill(this.boardArray[height - 1], 1);
        }
    }
}
```

The huge difference is that the first solution has `O(height*width)` time complexity and the second one just `O(width)`. That is a huge difference.

Answer (score 3):

There is a simple typo in your second loop:

```
for (int j = 0; i < width; ++i){
```

should be

```
for (int j = 0; j < width; ++j){
```

Also, the condition `i == height` will never be `true`, as in the first loop you test explicitly `i < height`.

And you can avoid using two loops when you need just one:

```
for (int j = 0; j < width; ++j){
    this.boardArray[0][j] = 1;
    this.boardArray[height-1][j] = 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this solution is more readable:

```
Arrays.fill(boardArray[0], 1);
Arrays.fill(boardArray[height-1], 1);
```

Comment: Thank you. Additional question: how can you fill columns instead of rows?